# replace a character in a /etc/passwd file without breaking system using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to harden a Ubuntu system and doing the 2 steps:

1. Running the following command and verifying no output is returned

> grep '^+:' /etc/passwd

2. If there is a output being returned then 
   Remove any legacy '+' entries from /etc/passwd if they exist.

I have written the following python function :

```
def passwd_safe():
    file = "/etc/passwd"
    for line in fileinput.input(file,inplace=1):
        if '+' in line:
            line = line.replace('+','')
        else:
            pass
```

But it seems like this doesn't work as expected , infact it overwrites the whole /etc/passwd file and leaves the system broken.

Comment: Are you adding sudo before running the file/function?

Comment: You should use `setpwent` instead. Check the [pwd module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pwd.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print the line to standard output:

```
def passwd_safe():
    file = "/etc/passwd"
    for line in fileinput.input(file,inplace=1):
        if not line.startswith('+'):
            print(line, end='')
```

Excerpt from [`fileinput`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

> Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument `inplace=True` is
>   passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file
>   is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input
>   file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it
>   will be replaced silently).

Comment: File "script.py", line 24
    print(line, end='')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you're using Python 2.7, add `from __future__ import print_function` on top of your script.

Comment: `if not line.startswith('+'):` , but  i am confused about this , if i replace '+' with 'x' , it should replace it with '' right ? , but it doesn't

Comment: I wrote `if not line.startswith('+'):` because you said you want to "remove any legacy `'+'` entries from `/etc/passwd`", so in my code I print the line only if the line does not start with `'+'`. If you are only looking to remove `'+'` characters from those lines, you can use your original code but simply add `print(line, end='')` after your `if` block.